# Random Questions specific number

Tags: php, wordpress

First thing i am not a expert but learning hard and still sucks and asking in this way is not correct on this platform so i am all in a way to your's help.

I have php function which randomly picks out any limited elements from the array each time. and my current plugin just shuffle's the order of elements. so whenever i put and replace the code in plugin it just breaks. so i am not understanding how to tackle it.

Here is the php function

```html
$array = [ 0=>'Q1', 1=>'Q2', 2=>'Q3', 3=>'Q4', 4=>'Q5' ];
$limit = 3;

rand_array($array, $limit);
function rand_array($array, $number){
print '<pre>';
shuffle($array);
print_r( array_values( array_intersect_key( $array, array_flip( array_rand( $array, $number ) ) ) ) );
reset($array);
}
```

This is the plugin which generates shuffle of elements of array

```js
<?php
/**
 * Plugin load class.
 */

// Prevent loading this file directly
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! class_exists( 'LP_Addon_Random_Quiz' ) ) {
/**
* Class LP_Addon_Random_Quiz
*/
class LP_Addon_Random_Quiz extends LP_Addon {

  
protected function _define_constants() {
define( 'LP_RANDOM_QUIZ_PATH', dirname( LP_ADDON_RANDOM_QUIZ_FILE ) );
}

protected function _init_hooks() {
add_filter( 'learn_press_quiz_general_meta_box', array( $this, 'admin_meta_box' ) );
   
add_filter( 'learn-press/quiz/questions', array( $this, 'random_questions' ), 10, 2 );

add_action( 'learn-press/user/quiz-redone', array( $this, 'update_user_questions' ), 100, 3 );
  }

/**
* Add random quiz option in quiz meta box.
*
* @param $meta_boxes
*
* @return mixed
*/
public function admin_meta_box( $meta_boxes ) {
$random_quiz = array(
array(
  'name' => __( 'Random Questions', 'learnpress-random-quiz' ),
   'id'   => '_lp_random_mode',
   'type' => 'yes_no',
   'desc' => __( 'Mix all available questions in this quiz.', 'learnpress-random-quiz' ),
   'std'  => 'no'
   )
   );

  foreach ( $random_quiz as $field ) {
 // add prerequisites option on top of admin settings course
 array_unshift( $meta_boxes['fields'], $field );
  }

  return $meta_boxes;
  }

  /**
   * Update user questions.
   *
   * @param $quiz_id
   * @param $course_id
   * @param $user_id
   */
 public function update_user_questions( $quiz_id, $course_id, $user_id ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $item = null;

  switch ( current_action() ) {
  case 'learn-press/user/quiz-redone':
  $item = $wpdb->get_row(
   $wpdb->prepare( "
   SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}learnpress_user_items
   WHERE item_id = %d
   AND user_id = %d
   AND ref_id = %d
   ORDER BY user_item_id DESC
   ", $quiz_id, $user_id, $course_id )
   );
   break;
   case 'learn-press/user/quiz-started':
   break;
   }
   if ( ! $item ) {
    return;
   }
   if ( ! $item->status == 'started' ) {
    return;
   }

   $random_quiz = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'random_quiz', true );
   $quiz        = LP_Quiz::get_quiz( $quiz_id );
   if ( $quiz && $questions = $quiz->get_questions() ) {
   $questions = array_keys( $questions );
   shuffle( $questions );
    $question_id = reset( $questions );

   // set user current question
   $user = learn_press_get_current_user();
   $user_course = $user->get_course_data( $course_id );
   $item_quiz = $user_course->get_item($quiz_id);

   $item_quiz->set_meta( '_current_question', $question_id );
   $item_quiz->update_meta();

   learn_press_update_user_item_meta( $item->user_item_id, 'current_question', $question_id );
   if ( empty( $random_quiz ) ) {
   $random_quiz = array( $quiz_id => $questions );
   } else {
   $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] = $questions;
   }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'random_quiz', $random_quiz );
   }
  }

  /**
   * Random quiz questions.
   *
   * @param $quiz_questions
   * @param $quiz_id
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function random_questions( $quiz_questions, $quiz_id ) {

  if ( get_post_meta( $quiz_id, '_lp_random_mode', true ) == 'yes' ) {

  // get user meta random quiz
  $random_quiz = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'random_quiz', true );
  if ( is_admin() || empty( $random_quiz ) || empty( $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] ) ) {
  return $quiz_questions;
  }
    
  $questions = array();
  if ( array_key_exists( $quiz_id, $random_quiz ) && sizeof( $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] ) == sizeof( $quiz_questions ) ) {
    
  foreach ( $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] as $question_id ) {
  if ( $question_id ) {
   $questions[ $question_id ] = $question_id;
   }
   }
   } else {
   $question_ids = array_keys( $quiz_questions );
   shuffle( $question_ids );
   $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] = $question_ids;
   $questions               = array();
   foreach ( $question_ids as $id ) {
   $questions[ $id ] = $quiz_questions[ $id ];
   }
    }

  return $questions;
   }

  return $quiz_questions;

  }
 }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'LP_Addon_Random_Quiz', 'instance' ) );
```

I know there is only a small change required but due to my lack of knowledge it is happening

Comment: _(...) whenever i put and replace the code in plugin it just breaks._ How? How does it break? Are you seeing any error messages? If so, what do they say? You'll have to be a bit more specific :P

Comment: Yes there are some if and else condition and other loops how can i manage the code safely with that. Can you look at the full code *second snippet and identify me where to paste and replace *first snippet code. I think i can see the shuffle function there on *second snippet which needs to be replace